# Can the C++ compiler optimize this away

Tags: c++

I have a small class which contains a `std::vector<double>` and some additional functionality:

```
class MyClass {

    double& operator[](std::size_t index) {
        return this->data[index];
    }
 
    std::vector<double>::iterator begin() {
         return this->data.begin();
    }

    std::vector<double>::iterator end() {
         return this->data.end();
    }

private:
    
    std::vector<double> data;
}
```

Since the `operator[]` and the `begin()/end()` iterators call directly to the `std::vector<double>` implementations - can the compiler optimize away my shims so there is no performance overhead compared to raw `std::vector<double>`?

Update1: I have tried creating a test implementation in godbolt.org - that worked although I am not at all familiar with reading those outputs.

Update2: Will close this as answered now - based on comment from `Aconcagua`

Comment: You can have a look at the generated assembly results and compare the two different implementations at godbolt.org

Comment: It can – and most likely will...

Comment: Thanks - I'll accept it if you promote the comment to an answer.

Comment: Class methods whose body is defined in header are automatically inlined

Comment: You can use the command `objdump` (if you are working on Linux) to extract your binary file and check if your custom member functions exist, if they exist, I don't think this kind of optimization happened.